# How to change Xcode setting to use Swift 1.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I installed the latest xcode and tried to upgrade my project to swift 1.2. I wanted to switch back to earlier version of swift 1.1.

Comment: There is no setting. [Download](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) an older Xcode version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the older version of Xcode on https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ all you need is to create an developer account.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple swift version install in machine than you can change the swift version for Xcode from `Xcode->Preferences->Toolchains` and select development snapshot instead of default

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Xcode 8.1:

As per the docs, `Switch between toolchains in the Toolchains pane of Components preferences. This pane is visible only when an alternative toolchain is installed.`

[...]

`Alternative toolchains must be manually installed into /Library/Developer/Toolchains/ or ~/Library/Developer/Toolchains/ to be recognized by Xcode and appear in the Toolchains pane of Components preferences.`

[image: Standard Xcode toolchain selected]

// Old response for XCode 7.3:

You can select which version of Swift you'd like to use in Xcode 7.3 via the following: (Menu) XCode > Toolchains > (select your version)

[image]